# how to exclude jar from fileTree in upstream projects?

Tags: gradle

We have the following configuration in a project...

```
configurations {
    //compile.exclude module: 'commons'
    //all*.exclude group: 'org.gradle.test.excludes', module: 'reports'
    all*.exclude module: 'log4j'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j',          name: 'slf4j-api',               version: '1.6.6'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j',          name: 'log4j-over-slf4j',        version: '1.6.6'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject',  name: 'guice',                   version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.protobuf',name: 'protobuf-java',           version: '2.4.1'
    //compile group: 'org.asteriskjava',name: 'asterisk-java',         version: '1.0.0.M3'   

    //to be erased soon
    compile group: 'commons-configuration',name:'commons-configuration',version: '1.8'
    //compile group: 'org.bouncycastle',   name: 'bcpg-jdk16',              version: '1.46'

    compile project(':sdi-master')
    compile project(':sdi-webserver')
}
```

unfortunately, the project sdi-webserver has it's own log4j brought in from a filetree like so

```
project(':sdi-webserver') {
    project.ext.genLibDir = file('lib')

    dependencies {    
        compile project(':sdi-master')
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
        compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/play-1.2.4/framework', include: 'play-*.jar')   
    }
```

How do we exclude this jar so it is not part of the dependencies.  The above excludes that we have only works for repositories and transitive dependencies and doesn't work for fileTree, but we still need to somehow exclude the jar file as we want eclipse task building correct .classpath, we want configurations.compile having accurate info for copying jars, etc. etc.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use an `exclude` on `fileTree`. Syntax is the same as for `include`.

Comment: well, that kinda stinks that I can't write some global exclude that works on all filetrees(and transitive stuff too).  oh well.

Comment: Gradle has no metadata for `fileTree` dependencies, so the usual excludes can't possibly work. Maybe we could provide a way to add metadata in the build script. Feel free to make a feature request.